# Is there a sort&compress feature in babelbib?

Tags: bibtex, babel, sorting, spanish

I am currently writing my Ph.D. thesis in Spanish and using babelbib. Is there a "sort&compress" feature in babelbib like there is in natbib?

Comment: IDK. But I am here to say **welcome**

Comment: Thank you, @Symbol1. I think I will simply edit a natbib style to cite in Spanish.